# SSRS: how to get top 3 in order Z to A

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I try to get in my diagram the top 3 of the worst value in SSRS:
my Code:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
    Select top 3
intervaldate as Datum
,Name 
,teamname as Team
,SUM(case when CounterName = 'Blown away' then calculationUnits else 0 end) as Blown
,Sum(case when CounterName = 'Thrown away' then calculationUnits else 0 end) as Thrown
,Sum(case when CounterName = 'total' then calculationUnits else 0 end) as Total

from Counting
where IntervalDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
    AND IntervalDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
and Name in (Select SystemID from tSystemView where SystemViewID = 2)     


group by intervaldate, teamName, Name
) c
```

Expression of the diagram:

```
=Sum(Fields!Blown.Value + Fields!Thrown.Value) / Sum(Fields!Total.Value) * 100
```

And I sorted it from highest to lowest
[image]

But it does not show me the right order.
If I choose every "Name" then it shows me other value then the top 3:

all Names with value:
[image: all Names with value]

top 3:
[image]

Comment: Why do you need the outer `Select` statement? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your top 3 statement is in the SQL while your sort is in the report. Without an `order by` SQL picks the top 3 random records. Also, unless there is more SQL you are not showing, the outer select is unnecessary. Add an `order by <column> desc` below your `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with Calcs as
(
select intervaldate as Datum,
       Name,
       TeamName, 
       SUM(case when CounterName = 'Blown away' then calculationUnits else 0 end) as Blown,
       Sum(case when CounterName = 'Thrown away' then calculationUnits else 0 end) as Thrown,
       Sum(case when CounterName = 'total' then calculationUnits else 0 end) as Total
from Counting
where IntervalDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
AND IntervalDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
and Name in (Select SystemID from tSystemView where SystemViewID = 2)  
group by intervaldate, teamName, Name
)
select b.*
from
(
  select a.*, row_number() over (order by (Blown + Thrown)/Total desc) as R_Ord  -- Change between ASC/DESC depending on needs
  from Calcs a
) b
where R_Ord <=3
```

Comment: how can I avoid "Divide by zero"

Comment: `IIF(Sum(Fields!Total.Value)  = 0, 0,Sum(Fields!Blown.Value + Fields!Thrown.Value) / Sum(Fields!Total.Value) * 100)`